# Rotate the group and scribbling on the group in a stage.. postting with code

Tags: html, kineticjs

Please this fiddle I have copied my complete project in it 
here if you open the fiddle in the output you can see an image, scribble on the image selecting pen,add text etc(like this perform some functions).then rotate the group using rotate button and then try to scribble you will understand what is the problem exactly.

In me view Problem is I am having a stage and a layer is added to the stage and a group is added to the layer and different elements like lines text etc are added to the group. then group is rotated the i am trying to draw the line based on the mouse position of the stage.But it is not coming correctly because the group got rotated the x and y what we are taking to draw a line is from stage.I need to take the x and y from the group not from the stage is their any way.If hav't understand please ask me or post a reply.

Comment: sorry missed adding the the code http://jsfiddle.net/akhiyadav1/k4qB8/22/

Comment: try caching the rotated image as a new image, deleting the old image, and placing the new one on the stage.

Comment: thanks for reply have you seen the code in the fidile for rotate.caching the rotated image as a new image means toImage()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you fairly close: http://jsfiddle.net/k4qB8/24/

```
// This rotates that added active line along with your group.
// This makes the draw direction correct
activeline.setRotationDeg(0-rootGroup.getRotationDeg());

// Here you'll have to figure a way to calculate how much to move the 
// line over so the draw is on the correct spot
// This is as close as I got it
     if(Math.abs(rootGroup.getRotationDeg()%360)==0)
           activeline.move(rootGroup.getX()-375, rootGroup.getY()-175);
     if(Math.abs(rootGroup.getRotationDeg()%360)==90)
           activeline.move(rootGroup.getX()-175, rootGroup.getY()+375);
     if(Math.abs(rootGroup.getRotationDeg()%360)==180)
           activeline.move(rootGroup.getX()+375, rootGroup.getY()+175);
     if(Math.abs(rootGroup.getRotationDeg()%360)==270)
           activeline.move(rootGroup.getX()+175, rootGroup.getY()-375);
```

Also, add some more logic for counter-clockwise rotation, as this doesn't work 100%.

I think the real solution would be to just draw on separate layers for each rotation, kind of like this:

```
 if (rotation is 90) : draw on lineLayer1;
 if (rotation is 180) : draw on lineLayer2;
 if (rotation is 270) : draw on lineLayer3;
 if (rotation is 360 || 0) : draw on lineLayer4;
```

This way you could just rotate the layers which are not drawn on to simulate the feel of rotation.

Comment: Is worked fine but same thing when i am applying for text its not working.